# How to create an off centered responsive background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a layout using bootstrap that has a bit of an odd background.

For interior pages it is divided into 2 unequal columns [7cols & 5cols] the left column needs a white background & the left needs a light grey background. Both backgrounds need to extend to the edges of the browser viewport regardless of the size. Here is a non-working example: http://dev.randallelectric.ca/

The problems really become apparent when you start resizing the browser window - the right hand column background should appear to maintain it's position behind the text.

I'm not sure how to correctly handle this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem happens because of this:

in bootstrap.min.css

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-7 {
width: 58.333333333333336%;
}
```

If you have width less than 768px, than width is being removed from .col-sm-7

And you can do this to get full width white background under 768px else will be your current background:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
div.content {
background: #ffffff;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.col-xs-7` and `.col-xs-5` instead.